# Rails 5: Add loop to create method and increment by 1 each time

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to add an `order_number` to my reservations. Now everytime an order gets created I want to change the value of the `order_number`.

I tried `@reservation.order_number = 1000` and then `@reservation.order_number += 1`, but I soon realised that this doesn't make any sense.

Here is my create method from my reservations controller:

```
def create
    service = Service.find(params[:service_id])

    if current_user.admin?
      flash[:alert] = "Du kannst nicht dein eigenes Angebot kaufen"
    elsif current_user.stripe_id.blank?
      flash[:alert] = "Füge eine Zahlungsmehtode hinzu"
      return redirect_to payment_method_path
    else
      @reservation = current_user.reservations.build
      @reservation.service = service
      @reservation.price = service.price
      @reservation.order_number = 1000

      if @reservation.Bearbeitung!
        flash[:notice] = "Ihre Anfrage wurde erfolgreich versendet"
        ReservationMailer.confirm_email_to_guest(@reservation.user, service).deliver
        confirm_sms(service, @reservation)
      else
        charge(service, @reservation)
      end

    end
    redirect_to submit_reservation_path(@reservation)
  end
```

Comment: I think you are better handling that at database level using an AUTO_INCREMENT column https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/example-auto-increment.html

Comment: I think your expected output 1000,1001,002,1003,etc.... i am a right?

Comment: @giri dharan yes. I added auto increment just didnt know that there is this option

Comment: Try @reservation.order_number = ModelName.last.order_number+1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your  model you can do something like,

```
before_save :add_order_number

private 
  def add_order_number
    default_order_number = 1000
    previous_order = Order.last
      if previous_order
        puts "last order_number was #{previous_order.order_number}"
        self.order_number = previous_order.order_number + 1
      else
        puts  "there was no last number, setting order number to default_order_number"
        self.order_number = default_order_number
      end
  end
```

Comment: Keep in mind that this won't work if any of the registries get updated. The query should be `previous_order = Order.order(:id).last`